# Cannot resolve symbol @android:color/X anymore

Tags: android, android-xml, android-color, android-attributes

Before, we were able to use the android-provided colors:

```
@android:color/white
```

,

```
@android:color/red
```

, and

```
@android:color/yellow
```

And so on.

**However,** *THEY SUDDENLY disappeared.* I now get a "cannot resolve symbol '`@android:color/white`' " error.

What's going on? Where'd the easy-to-access colors go?

**Note:** Android Studio can resolve `android`, but not `@android:color/white`.

Comment: can you add your xml file where you got problem

Comment: try rebuilding the index and restarting

Comment: try defining your colors in colors.xml in the resources folder

Comment: @SachinSuthar It's EVERYWHERE.

Comment: @Azola I don't want to since it has too much code. THat's why I use the android attr

Comment: ok but you rebuld and clean project.

Comment: @SachinSuthar tried

Comment: It's definitely an index issue... sometimes android studio stupidly screws up the R.java and the indexes and only ways to rectify it are gradle sync... invalidate indexes restart and then rebuild and clean...

Comment: try this.after define color.
getResources().getColor(R.color.red);

Comment: I just created a scrap Android Studio 2.2 project, put `android:textColor="@android:color/white"` in the "Hello, world" `TextView`, and Android Studio is not complaining. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare what else is there to add? This is happening everywhere. Setting button text color, setting text color, setting button background color, setting Secondary Text color, etc.

Comment: "what else is there to add?" -- one or more resource files that are giving you the error, plus your `build.gradle` files. You might consider creating a scrap Android Studio project, independent of your existing one, and trying the same test that I did. If that fails, the issue probably is tied to your Android Studio and SDK installation (though this would surprise me). If it succeeds, then the issue is somewhere in your project.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am well aware of that, but before doing heavy-duty stuff I need to make sure it isn't an update in the SDK or support repo.

Comment: @Kushan Invalidate caches/restart worked for me. You were right, please  post this answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @CommonsWare ... AS usually screws up the indexes in a project (eg R.java not found and android properties not accessible) ... it's unfortunate that it happens, have had to scrap plenty of projects due to this stupid issue... I usually like to sync it on Git for this exact reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try rebuilding the index and restarting.

It's most definitely an index issue... sometimes android studio stupidly screws up the R.java and the indexes and only ways to rectify it are gradle sync... invalidate indexes restart and then rebuild and clean...

Comment: glad to help @AbAppletic